# Using If Statements in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to work out how to work If statements while creating a function in Google Spreadsheets.

I've provided an example of what I'm trying to achieve. To the best of my knowledge, the If statement in this code simply checks that the value of cell A4 is equal to 4, and if so then it multiplies the input number by 1.5? However, when I try to run the function it always returns 0 (or whatever value I assign the price variable to begin with).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

```
    function calculatePrice(inNum) {

         var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
         var price = 0;

         if (sheet.getRange(1, 4).getValue() == 4) {
             price = inNum * 1.5;
         }

         return price;
     }
```

Comment: How are you running the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.
You were missing the getDataRange, after that you can get the cell.

```
function calculatePrice(inNum) {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var price = 0;
 if (sheet.getDataRange().getCell(row, col).getValue() == 4) {
  price = inNum * 1.5;
 }
 return price;
}
```

Demo of the [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ar3UFFcF-_ZSdEpob0NmR1Foc0JXcU16SkFIVTR2Nnc&usp=sharing)

Comment: Why do you think `getDataRange` is required? [`getRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer)) looks just fine.

Comment: With getDataRange I am getting all the range of the cells. I include a demo to show how it works

Comment: I get exactly the same result with this code that I get with the OP's code, which is: It seems to work at first, but the function result is cached or something, because subsequently it doesn't update -- not if I change A1, and not if I delete the cell using the function and type it in again. I find it curious the OP marked this as "accepted," but hopefully it worked for them.

Comment: @T.J Crowder The problem is that the function will update the input of the value I send in parameters. He wants to use a formula using the google app script. The best could be to only do =if(A1=4,C3*1.5,0)

Answer (score 1):

As T.J.Crowder spotted, the accepted answer has a critical weakness. The custom function is dependent upon values in `A4`, yet it does not automatically update when that value is changed.

Why? As an optimizing step, Sheets will only refresh cells that it determines are affected by editing. However, it does not analyze the internals of custom functions, relying instead on the range reference arguments in spreadsheet formulas.

If it was important that your function respond to changes in `A4`, it would be better to implement it to accept that `importantFactor` as an argument, thusly:

```
function calculatePrice(importantFactor,inNum) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var price = 0;
  if (importantFactor == 4) {
    price = inNum * 1.5;
  }
  return price;
}
```

To be used like this, assuming `inNum` is the value in `G6`:

```
=calculatePrice($A$4,G6)
```

Better yet, you could achieve this without scripts:

```
=IF($A$4=4, G6 * 1.5, 0)
```

Either way, a change to the content of `A4` would trigger a recalculation of the cells containing the formula.